# Bootstrap resampling

Tags: r

I am trying to do bootstrap resampling with the following code.I got this code from http://spark.rstudio.com/ahmed/bootstrap/ . I would like to draw the same plots from the website using my datasets. data1 and data2 are text files contain only one column.

```
a = read.table("/home/Desktop/data1.txt")
b = read.table("/home/Desktop/data2.txt")
diff.observed = mean(b) - mean(a)
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(b) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(a) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> diff.observed 
[1] NA
```

I don't get the mean value of the observed dataset.

```
alpha = 0.05

# Number of replicates
n = 1000

# Difference between means of bootstrapped datasets (n replicates)
diff.bootstrap = NULL

for (i in 1 : n) {
    # Sample with replacement
    a.bootstrap = sample  (a, length(a), TRUE)
    b.bootstrap = sample  (b, length(b), TRUE)

    diff.bootstrap[i] = mean(b.bootstrap) - mean(a.bootstrap)
}
 plot(density(a.bootstrap))
 plot(density(b.bootstrap))
 plot(density(diff.bootstrap))
Error in density.default(diff.bootstrap) : 'x' contains missing values
```

I don't understand the mistake. Your suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: The `mean` method for data.frames is defunct since R version 3.0.0.

Comment: This is unrelated to the error in your code, but you might want to look into the packages `boot` and `bootstrap` for much more performant alternatives to your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may load your data into a `matrix` then the `mean` should work:

```
a = as.matrix(read.table ("data1.txt"))
b = as.matrix(read.table ("data2.txt"))
diff.observed = mean(b) - mean(a)
```